# Is using extra whitespace to make MySQL queries more readable inefficient to the point of not being worth it?

Tags: mysql, whitespace

Lets say I have a query

UPDATE foo.bar SET crop=5 WHERE soil='brown'

I would write this as so:

```
UPDATE  
  foo.bar  
SET  
  crop = 5  
WHERE  
  soil = 'brown'
```

I write queries in this format to make them more readable in my code.  However, this is being transfered between a web server and a DB server, so I assume that the wasted space will take up some bandwidth and have some slowdown in transfer.

Assuming I am writing much larger queries, ones that take 20+ lines, is this inefficient to the point of not being worth it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always write your queries such that they are maximally readable.  If you are really worried about saving bytes transferred to and from the server you can run your queries through a database connector and set the options such that extraneous whitespace is removed.  This might already be happening with your current code.  Have you actually snooped on the SQL data that is being sent across the network to see what it looks like?

Comment: No, I haven't sniffed, but I know the connection setup isn't doing anything special.  I did look at the code, and there is an option to turn on compression in the mysql connection.  I will turn this on.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no great difference in efficiency. Readability is the virtue that should win out. If you are really concerned with efficiency and you frequently use queries that differ only in parameter values, you could consider using prepared statements, for which the query execution plan is only calculated once (with a corresponding increase in efficiency).

Answer (score 1):

You should format the queries in such a way that you and everybody in your team understands them even 6 months after you have written them.

The whitespace will not affect the query speed in any way.

Comment: I'm not worried about the speed of the MySQL engine performing the queries, I'm worried about the hit to data transfer over the network. Would you still say this is not a concern?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about then network either. Adding formatting just adds a tiny little overhead to the amount of data sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, this is premature optimization. Do you have metrics that establish a tangible performance difference? Code should be written to be read. Let me put it this way, which would you rather read:

```
Update foo.bar
Set crop = 5
Where soil = 'brown'

uPdAte fOo.bAr sEt cRoP=5 wHErE sOil='brown'
```

Readability matters. It matters far more than minute performance differences.